# Trying to append a HTML ID to a URL on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been looking around for an answer and can't seem to find what I need. I have a simple web project that has a list of images. When you click on one of those images it opens up a detais template about that project and populates the data with a js object I created. I'm using local storage to use for the js objects and display the correct one based on the index value of links on the home page.

This is the code that handles the clicks on the home page

```
var gridBtnsArray = $(".hero-btn");

$(".hero-btn").on("click" , function(){
    console.log($(".hero-btn").index(this));
    localStorage.setItem("indexValue", $(".hero-btn").index(this));
    window.document.location = './detail.html';
})
```

And I'm using this code to populate the details on the details.html page.

`console.log(localStorage.getItem("indexValue"));
 console.log(students[localStorage.getItem("indexValue")].name);
 console.log(students[localStorage.getItem("indexValue")].projectImages[0]);`

What I would like to do is click on one of the images on the home screen to be taken to the details page ( which it does now ) but instead of the URL being this site.com/details.html.  I would like it to me site.com/details#idName.
I would also like to figure out a way to be able to share that URL and have the local stored object also be sent with it so that the correct page opens up when shared.

Comment: What happens if someone visits `/detail.html` by typing in the address, or shares the URL once they get there? It seems like a more straightforward approach would be to create HTML pages for each image and use `<a>` links.

Answer (score 0):

The hash for a page is stored in `window.location.hash`.

So, to change the hash value for a page:

```
window.location.hash = '#yourHashString'
```

Ref: [Location: hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash)

If you want to redirect to a new page with a hash, just add it to the new path:

```
window.document.location = './detail.html' + '#yourHashString';
```

To act upon your hash string when the page loads, do something like this:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let myHashString = window.location.hash;
  setupMyPage(myHashString);
}
```